# Android button in dialog registering 2 times

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

i have a dialog that displays on screen and 5 buttons on it.One of the buttons sometimes ( 1 of 30 cases or so ) registers twice. Button onClick event makes a request through HTTP API. Now, when i look at the logs i see that request came in the same second ( witch also is visible in the logCat ). The problem is that i can't reproduce the issue but it's there. I am implementing the onClick listeners programatically button.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener()...);

Any ides ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    Dialog dialog;
Button button1;
Button button2;
Button button3;
Button button4;
Button button5;

public void showDialog(String serviceID) {
    if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
        return;
    }
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_dialog);
    dialog.show();
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    button1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_1);
    button2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_2);
    button3 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_3);
    button4 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_4);
    button5 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_5);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button1.setEnabled(false);
            /* Code */
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button2.setEnabled(false);
            /* Code */
        }
    });
    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button3.setEnabled(false);
            /* Code */
        }
    });
    button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button4.setEnabled(false);
            /* Code */
        }
    });
    button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button5.setEnabled(false);
            /* Code */
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: add your code where you create the buttons

Comment: It could be the network you are connecting, Ill say a delay.

Comment: @DroidChris, here's the code...

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin, don't think so, because the double tap is registered on android side, and on server side i get 2 requests in a row.

Comment: how do you call showDialog()?

Comment: @DroidChris through a sub-menu, but it's opened only once, because i have also implemented if(subMenu != null && !subMeni.isShowing()){return;} so if it's registered there as a double click it will have only 1 instance of the dialog

Comment: I would like to see what it triggering this

Comment: The subMenu is triggerd through listView.setOnItemClickListener witch is initated in Main class,

lvService.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (position >= 0 && main != null && main.LIST_services.size() != 0) {
     viewServiceDetails(main.LIST_services.get(position), false);
    }
   }
  });

viewServiceDetails is method that is opening subMenu